# Is it right to give equal chances?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In a certain town, the probability that it will rain in the afternoon is known to be $0.6$ Moreover, meteorological data indicates that if the temperature at noon is less than or equal to $ 25°C$, the probability that it will rain in the afternoon is $ 0.4$. The temperature at noon is equally likely to be above$ 25°C$, or at/below $25°C$. What is the probability that it will rain in the afternoon on a day when the temperature at noon is above $25°C$____?

---

My attempt:

$\implies P(\text{rain in afternoon}) = 0.5 \times P(\times{rain when temp \leq25}) + 0.5 \times P(\text{ rain when temp>25})$,

$\implies 0.6 = 0.5\times 0.4 + 0.5\times P( \text{rain when temp>25})$

So,
$P( \text{rain when temp>25}) = 0.8$

I am using the rule $P(R)=(1/2)\times P(A)+(1/2)\times P(B)$ , I applied it , but I have no clear point , why I gives the priority to equal , why I don't give the chances to not equal $(i.e.  P(R)=(2/3)\times P(A)+(1/3)\times P(B)$ ).

> > Can you explain it in a formal way, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full equation reads:

$$P(\text{rain}) = P(T>25)\cdot P(\text{rain if } T>25) +
 P(T\le 25)\cdot P(\text{rain if } T\le 25).\tag 1$$

The problem statement explicitly contains:

> The temperature at noon is equally likely to be above 25°C, or at/below 25°C.

That is, $P(T>25) = P(T\le 25)$. Since $P(T>25) + P(T\le 25) = 1$, it immediately follows that $P(T>25) = P(T\le 25) = \frac12$.

Inserting in (1) immediately gives your equation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$,$G_{25}$,$L_{25}$,  denote the events that it rains in the afternoon, the temperature is greater than $25$, the temperature is less than $25$, respectively.

We have the following data: $P(R)=0.6$, $P(G_{25})=P(L_{25})=0.5$, $P(R\mid L_{25})=0.4$.

The question is

$$P(R\mid G_{25})=\frac{P(R\cap G_{25})}{0.5}=2(P(R)-P(R\cap L_{25}))=$$
$$=2(P(R)-P(R\mid L_{25})P(L_{25}))=2(0.6-0.4\times0.5)=0.8.$$